# foreach isn't reading well through .descendants and goes to else statement before if

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm still learning in terms of C#

I'm currently working on a filter system and have an if statement list that prevents user to from performing any actions. Now is it that whenever the user submits an ID, my foreach is supposed to run through the list of already submitted ID's checking whether they exist already or not.

The bug is that when the user submits an already existing ID, it will not see the existing ID in the first run so it will create and fill in a node, but in the second run it does so it sends an error message & breaks the session.

My code:

```
private async void btnAddId_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            Xdoc.Load(xmldoc);
            XmlNode NodeEl = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/filter/filter_item");
            XmlNode NodeList = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/filter");

            var root = XDocument.Load(xmldoc).Root;
            var filter = root.Element("filter");
            int parsedValue;

            foreach (var f in filter.Descendants())
            {
                if (f.Value == tbAddId.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value already exists in the orderlist!");
                }
                else if (!int.TryParse(tbAddId.Text, out parsedValue))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Input isn't numeric!");
                }
                else if (tbAddId.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
                }
                else if (tbAddId.Text == "Add ID")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
                }
                else if (NodeList.InnerText == "")
                {
                    NodeEl.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;
                    tbAddId.Text = "Add ID";
                    tbAddId.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
                    await api.config_Load();
                    await api.Page_Load();
                }
                else
                {
                    XmlNode filterItem = Xdoc.CreateElement("filter_item");
                    NodeList.AppendChild(filterItem);
                    filterItem.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;
                }

                tbOrderDisplay.Text += f.Value + " ";
            }         

            Xdoc.Save(xmldoc);
        }
```

XML content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <bol_client_id></bol_client_id>
  <!--- this is the client id-->
  <bol_client_secret></bol_client_secret>
  <!-- this is the client secret -->
  <customer_id></customer_id>
  <company_phone></company_phone>
  <auth_token_url></auth_token_url>
  <bol_orders_url></bol_orders_url>
  <debug_mode>true</debug_mode>
  <filter>
    <filter_item>1172828940</filter_item>
    <filter_item>1173700637</filter_item>
  </filter>
</root>
```

Comment: Ofc, I'll edit it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether value exists before you try to insert it:

```
private async void btnAddId_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    Xdoc.Load(xmldoc);
    XmlNode NodeEl = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/filter/filter_item");
    XmlNode NodeList = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/filter");

    var root = XDocument.Load(xmldoc).Root;
    var filter = root.Element("filter");
    int parsedValue;

    //1. Check for duplicates
    foreach (var f in filter.Descendants())
    {
        if (f.Value == tbAddId.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value already exists in the orderlist!");
            tbOrderDisplay.Text += f.Value + " ";
            return;
        }
    }

    //2. Validate and insert
    if (!int.TryParse(tbAddId.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input isn't numeric!");
    }
    else if (tbAddId.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
    }
    else if (tbAddId.Text == "Add ID")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
    }
    else if (NodeList.InnerText == "")
    {
        NodeEl.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;
        tbAddId.Text = "Add ID";
        tbAddId.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
        await api.config_Load();
        await api.Page_Load();
    }
    else
    {
        XmlNode filterItem = Xdoc.CreateElement("filter_item");
        NodeList.AppendChild(filterItem);
        filterItem.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;
    }

    Xdoc.Save(xmldoc);
}
```